# Getting a "BAD_ENVIRONMENT" error when trying to join Agora.io call due to browser update

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I'm using the Javascript AgoraSDK. When trying to join a call, I'm getting a "join channel error BAD_ENVIRONMENT" failure. Everything was working fine up until today.

I took a look at the Agora docs. This error is associated with unsupported Web Browsers. My Chrome just updated today so I expect that was what caused the issue. I tried on another browser and it worked fine.

Has anyone else experienced this and what's the best way to resolve it?
Is there anything I need to do or will agora automatically update to support the latest version of the chrome browser?

Comment: Try using their official support channels. What do you expect anyone here to be able to do about it?

Comment: Was about to write the same, try to get support from devrel@agora.io or join them on [Slack](https://agoraiodev.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-pwtdea07-Oq0VrEPxW7ooiGxiuTxopg#/shared-invite/email).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the 3.x version of the Agora Web SDK - the new release (v3.6.10) of the SDK fixes some known issues with Chrome, I'd suggest updating to the latest SDK.

[Release Notes](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/release_web_video?platform=Web)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by updating the Agora SDK to 3.6.2 but only issue i am facing is audio